# Byte allocation in short unsigned data

Tags: c

kindly check the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
        char *Date= NULL;
        unsigned short y=2013;
        Date =  malloc(3);
        sprintf((char *)Date,"%hu",y);  
        printf("%d %d %d %d %d \n",Date[0],Date[1],Date[2],Date[3],Date[4]);

        printf("%s %d %d",Date,strlen(Date),sizeof(y));
}

output:
50 48 49 51 0
2013 4 2
```

How I am getting the string length 4 instead 2,as I am putting a short integer value into the memory so it should be occupied in 2 byte of memory.But how it is taking 4 byte.

How each byte getting 2 0 1 3 from the input, instead 20 in one byte and 13 in another byte.

I want to put 20 to one byte and 13 to another byte.How to do that.kindly tell something

Kindly give some answer.

Comment: That's what `sprintf(Date,"%hu",y);` does, convert the number to its decimal string representation. 2013 has four digits, hence you need four characters to display it (plus a 0-terminator). You have allocated only three bytes, so you have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

As indicate by its name, the sprintf function write a formated *string*. So, your number 2013 is converted to "2013" (a 5 character string).

Comment: Thanks for answer,this means what ever I will put in the string it will always be calculated on the no of characters(bytes) available on the source.am I correct.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure to correctly understand your question (maybe because english is not my mother tongue)... Anyway, the essential is to understand that sprintf replaces each format by the “stringified“ version of the target parameter (except if it is already a string, of course).

Comment: @pradipta Do you want to store `20` in `date[0]`, `13` in `date[1]` and then print the string? ASCII chars 20 & 13 are not printable. So you can store them like that but you can't print the string.

Answer (score 3):

You are invoking *undefined behaviour*.

You have allocated only 3 bytes for `Date` and storing 5 bytes.

Four bytes for `2013` and 1 NUL byte. So you should allocate at least 5 bytes if you want to store `2013`.

---

If you want to transfer a stream of bytes then I suggest you do in the following way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
        unsigned char *Date= NULL;
        unsigned short y=2013;
        unsigned char *p;

        p = (unsigned char*) &y;
        Date =  malloc(3);
        Date[0] = *p;
        Date[1] = *(p+1);
        Date[2] = 0;

        printf("%s %d %d",Date,strlen(Date),sizeof(y));
}
```

This outputs:

```
� 2 2
```

The strange char is because interpreting some byte values as a string. Plain char may be signed or unsigned depending on your implementation. So use unsigned char to avoid incorrect interpretation of bytes.

Comment: -1: While this is entirely correct information, it doesn't answer the question being asked.

Comment: @pradipta `Date[0]=y/100; Date[1]=y%100; Date[2]=0;` will store the `20` at index 0, `13` at index 1 and terminating it with NUL will give the 3 byte data. I am not sure if that's what OP wants. May be, if you tell the purpose that'll be useful to give a better answer. As the ASCII chars are not printable. DO you want to pass it over a network or something?

Comment: Thanks for the answer,yes I want to send it in network but my question is about why that sprintf not able to store data in 2 byte which I got as sprintf storing a formatted string so,it is storing one characher in one byte,but your solution looks good.I am not getting ASCII chars are not printable can you explain something.

Comment: @pradipta I meant that if you print ASCII chars as string then you get some chars as in my edit. Even though the bytes are stored correctly, you can inspect anything by printing it as string.